# How to find the number of bytes of an integer value stored in a integer variable

Tags: c#, string

I need to pass an argument in a function to connect to a server which has to contain the xml(which I am passing through a string variable). But the server assumes that first 4 bytes of the data stream which I am sending is the length of the xml (in bytes). I have found out the length of the number of byte in the string by

```
int strlen= System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(ngconnect);
```

Now the next thing is I need to pass the data to the server which has to contain the data as

> First 4 bytes as the length of the string
>   Then the actual data stream.

The code which I have written is

```
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strlen+ngconnect);
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
```

Which I dont think is correct. So please do tell me how should I append the length of the string in the argument such that it is exactly of 4 bytes.

Comment: You are mixing two different encodings: `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode` which is UTF16, and `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII` which is ASCII (and will be wrong if you want to support any non-ASCII characters).

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes sir definitely you are right. I corrected that part of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `int` in c# is a 32bit number so its already 4bytes, you just need to convert it to bytes

```
byte[] strlenBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(strlen);
```

and then transmit the info to the server in parts:

```
serverStream.Write(strlenBytes , 0, strlenBytes .Length);
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ngconnect);
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
```